# How do I reset password retry count for a user in the gpu using C#

Tags: c#, passwords

I'm using this piece of code :

```
// create a "principal context" - e.g. your domain (could be machine, too)
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN");

// validate the credentials
bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("myuser", "mypassword")
```

to check for user passwords in the GPU. But I heard that it increment there password retry count and I would not like that to happen. How can I reset there retry password count?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't that break the security? The only way to reset the retry count should be to reset the password or log in with a correct password.

Comment: Why would that break security?, I am the admin, I should be able to do whatever I want...

Comment: Because if you could do that, then all users passwords would be open for admins and that is not the case. The Admin can RESET a password as a last way out if a user has forgot the password or the user is not active anymore. And the point is that the USER will KNOW that this has happend.

If it would be possible to reset the counter, then its the same as have the password in clear text for admins, and thats not the case.